# How to visualize cotangent spaces.

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, visualization

I was wondering how to intuitively and visually understand dual vector spaces and one-forms. So my question is (1), how to visualize cotangent spaces and (2), how to intuitively understand them? My guess is that by answering the first question, I then gain an intuitive understanding, but if there are other tips, they would be welcome.

Comment: Yes, how do you visualize dual spaces is the question. This is primarily aimed at simple manifolds where visualization is possible.

Comment: This is roughly how I imagine dual vector spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form#Visualizing_linear_functionals

Comment: The link was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have an inner product $g$ on a vector space, you can identify vectors $X$ with covectors $Y \mapsto g(X, Y)$. So, if you have a differentiable Riemannian metric $g$ on a differentiable manifold, it determines a bundle isomorphism $TM \to T^*M$. Every differentiable manifold admits a differentiable Riemannian metric, so at least at the level of differentiable bundles, the tangent and cotangent manifolds look the same.

Comment: (Caveat: In general there is no preferred Riemannian metric on a differentiable manifold, and different metrics give different isomorphisms.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I have just begun to read about manifolds in Sean Carroll's book about General Relativity, so have just learned about tangent vector spaces and bundles, dual spaces, and metrics.

Comment: Enjoy, it's a great topic. Most DG questions here seem to get good answers, so you might find useful asking more questions on this site as you work through the text.